# Voiceover reads button as button list

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

I have the following button in one of my web pages.

For some reason, Voiceover/Chrome will read "Add the new customer, button list 2 items".

I have no idea why it is being read like this.

On JAWS/IE11, it reads correctly as "Add the new customer, button". 
Any ideas?

```html
<button aria-label="Add the new customer" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addNewCustomer()">Add</button>
```

Comment: what HTML is before and after it?

Comment: agreed @johannes, more context is needed.  the 'btn' and 'btn-primary' class might also be affecting things, but it's hard to say without seeing more of the html.  if i were to paste the one line button example into chrome and run voiceover, it would just read it as a button and not say anything about a list.  there's other code at play here.